# Multi-tenant Service using Spring webflux

Tags: spring-boot, multi-tenant, spring-webflux

I am trying to implement multi-tenant service using Spring web flux.I have read examples of using AbstractRoutingDataSource and ThreadLocal TenantContext to populate the tenantId for mapping datasource cofigurations. However with Web Flux we cannot use ThreadLocal and therefore this solution.
With WebFlux, I can read the tenant configuration which is a part of my User Principle -

```
ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
            .map(Authentication::getPrincipal).cast(UserPrincipal.class).flatMap(user -> {
                TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(user.getTenantID().toString())
```

However I am not sure how to **not** use ThreadLocal. Can I use SubscriberContext for performing the same action?
Any example or help would be much apprecited.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, SubscriberContext is the way to go. Have a look at: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context

Comment: Could you please share an example if possible. AbstractRoutingDataSource  does not seem to support reactive calls since its context is bound with ThreadLocal. Please correct if I am wrong

Comment: Yes, you cannot use AbstractRoutingDataSource, because it uses ThreadLocal. Have a look at: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/98

Comment: Thanks Salil. like AbstractRoutingDatasource, With AbstractRoutingConnectionFactory knowledge of all Tenant datasource is required before hand. However, we are looking for identifying the tenant and then configuring the datasource based on its configurations. However Thanks for answering my question above.